# Jquery resize load

Tags: jquery, window-resize

Can anyone point out to my why the resize function isn't working?
I have to reload the page to get the different width functions firing.

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(e) {

  if (parseInt($(window).width()) > 620) {

    $(".nav-button a").click(function() {
      $(".nav-large").slideToggle('slow');
      $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });

  }


  if (parseInt($(window).width()) < 620) {

    $(".nav-button a").click(function() {
      $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
      $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });
    $('.overlay').on('click', function() {
      $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
      $(".nav-button a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
      open = false;
    });

  }
}).resize();
```

Comment: what if the window width is exactly 620 ? why aren't you simply using an `if else` statement ?

Comment: it would also be helpful to share some of your html markup

Comment: something else must be the problem, you function fires well, with correct values here, [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmev9drf/)

Comment: NOTE: you shouldn't be giving new event handlers the way you do in an event such as resize, that fires the function a lot of times. Previous functions bound to the event still exist, and if you toggle something twice, it's just like you do nothing. A proper way would be to use named function, and unbind them with `.off` before binding new ones

Comment: ^-- or use delegate bindings with child selectors specific to the cases, so then all you have to do is change element to match the different child selectors and then you don't have to juggle bindings at all.